# Xamarin iOS Get the connected Bluetooth device name in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a cross platform application and I need to get the connected Bluetooth device's Name iOS platform.

I tried with below code

```
if (BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter != null && BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.IsEnabled)
        {
            foreach (var pairedDevice in BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BondedDevices)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Found device with name: {pairedDevice.Name} and MAC address: {pairedDevice.Address}");
            }
        }
```

but it's work only with Android platform.

Comment: `BluetoothAdapter` in a class in Android . If you want to implement it both on iOS and Android in froms, check https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle#setup .